# Trying to set a default background picture using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to Angular.js and I'm running into a problem. I'm using ng-repeat to iterate through a list of news items. Each item has a Title and Body, but will have an optional picture url that will be used as the background.

I can get the news item elements with picture URLs to display when there is a url present. See sample code below.

```
<li class="news-item col-md-6" ng-repeat="announcement in news.announcements | limitTo:8" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{announcement.Url}})'}">
```

I need to set the    announcement.Url value to a default background picture URL when announcement.Url is NULL or Undefined. Not sure how I can go about this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<li class="news-item col-md-6" ng-repeat="announcement in news.announcements | limitTo:8" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{announcement.Url || \'path to default image\'}})'}">
```

Anything between `{{` and `}}` is an angular expression (similar to javascript itself as far as a beginner is concerned). You can simply include the `||` operator (a logical OR) and put the path to your default image in a string after that. If `announcement.Url` is null or undefined then it will be "falsy" and the latter half of the OR conditional will be used.

Edit: Notice that I escaped the string delimiters (`\'`) because they are already nested inside a string that uses those delimiters.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Alex. It actually worked without the escaping.

Comment: Oh Angular you sly dog ;)